# Laravel Inner Join With Both Null Column Values

Tags: laravel, eloquent, inner-join

I will have to write an inner join with custom SELECT statement in it and one of the conditions required is to get those rows which have matching null values in the columns, I was able to get the relationship in raw sql statment with `(a.<col> = b.<col> OR (a.<col> IS NULL AND b.<col> IS NULL))` but I do not know how to write it using Laravel Eloquent. What is the inner join with OR in Laravel Eloquent? I have tried with `$join->on('a.<col>', '=', 'b.<col>')->where('a.<col>', '=', DB::raw(NULL))->where('b.<col>', '=', DB::raw(NULL));` but it doesn't give me the expected result.

Comment: ```Eloquent``` here

Comment: I have a payment table and I will have to get the sum of the amount column in the table  and grab a list of the payment id as well. So I need to have ```Payment::select('SUM(amount)', 'p.ids', 'ref_no')->groupBy('p.ids', 'ref_no);``` and the statement is incomplete as I do not know how to use ```inner join``` here. So, the p.ids is actually from the same table (payment) which I inner join with. The working raw SQL query is ```inner join (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) as pmt_ids, ref_no as rn FROM payment group by rn) AS p on payment.ref
_no = p.rn OR (payment.ref_no IS NULL AND p.rn IS NULL)```

Comment: For ```OR (payment.ref_no IS NULL AND p.rn IS NULL```, I do not know how to construct it with ```Laravel Eloquent```